# Flutter App Crashing when app compiled for apk or aab

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

I have to applications that I developed with flutter . When I run the project in android studio , it works without any problems , but when I convert it to apk or aab format and try it on the phone or emulator some of the functionality of the applications does not work . I did try in emulator and physical device but not works . What is the reason ? I would appreciate it if you help , I think it is sourced from gradle , my gradle and pubspec codes in below

Android\buildgradle :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app\buildgradle :

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.iakbas.welat.question_solver"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.

            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:17.0.2'
}
```

pubspec :

```
name: text_extract_google_mi_kit
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

CFBundleVersion.
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_ml_kit: ^0.7.2
  http: ^0.13.5
  camera: ^0.10.0
  permission_handler: ^8.2.2
  image_crop: ^0.4.1
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  lottie: ^2.3.2
  google_mobile_ads: ^3.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/icons/keyboardicon.png
    - assets/icons/listicon.png
    - assets/icons/settings64.png
    - assets/animations/aiautomation.json
```

Comment: Can you, please, share an exception text here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when I run the "flutter run --release" command , the app haven't issue . when I run the flutter build apk the apk not working healthly . the image_crop library not working healthlty